# Trim everything after symbol and also search for other fields SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, string-function

I have a number of fields in a database that i need to pull information from. For the name column the data is in the following format:

```
Jim John - 1234567
```

I only want the name section, therefore trim everything from the "-" onwards. I've tried the following

```
"SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('-',name)-1),'_',' '), othername, streetname, postal, 
                                        nameID, helper, helperID

        FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[nameDB] with (nolock) 

        WHERE
              (othername like '" & txtSearch.Text & "' 
               or postal like '" & txtSearch.Text & "') 
               and (postal not like '%Error%' 
               and postal not like '%nas_admin%'
               and postal not like '%NASAdmin%'
               and postal like '[A-z][A-z][A-z]%')"
```

This doesn't work, is it possible that i can trim the data and also search for other data in other fields?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using `Substring`

```
  SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(name, 0, CHARINDEX('-', name)) AS [name] , othername, streetname, postal, 
                                        nameID, helper, helperID

        FROM [ARDVARC].[dbo].[nameDB] with (nolock) 

        WHERE
              (othername like '" & txtSearch.Text & "' 
               or postal like '" & txtSearch.Text & "') 
               and (postal not like '%Error%' 
               and postal not like '%nas_admin%'
               and postal not like '%NASAdmin%'
               and postal like '[A-z][A-z][A-z]%')"
```

hope this helps.

Comment: say i wanted to also do this to the OTHERNAME field, would i just copy the same code and add it after?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE('Jim John - 1234567','-','.'),2)
```

Result:

```
name      
--------- 
Jim John
```

So you can use it as

```
SELECT 
     PARSENAME(REPLACE(NAME, '-', '.'), 2) NAME
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(othername, '-', '.'), 2) othername
    ,streetname
    ,postal
    ,nameID
    ,helper
    ,helperID
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[nameDB] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ...
```

---

[`Parsename()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx),[`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)